# Force execution of build action hook on Openshift

Tags: java, git, openshift

I have an Openshift Online application, created with Spring boot and based on a DIY cartridge. It basically loads Java 8 and Maven from the web (action hook `pre_start`), builds my Java 8 Maven project (action hook `build`) and starts the application (action hook `start`).

When I push something in the git repository, it usually runs the maven build and everything works. But sometimes, during the build phase, I get an exception:

```
(....)
remote: [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ earweb ---
remote: [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
remote: [INFO] Compiling 39 source files to /var/lib/openshift/12312d12312ef12312312/app-root/runtime/repo/target/classes
Connection to myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: error in sideband demultiplexer
To ssh://12312d12312ef12312312@myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com/~/git/myproject.git/
   0470c33..d9e2857  master -> master
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://12312d12312ef12312312@myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com/~/git/myproject.git/'
```

Now the application is not running and when I start it, the old application is loaded (because the `build` step did not finish).

Is there a way to force the execution of the [Openshift Default Build Lifecycle](https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#default-build-lifecycle) without creating a git commit/push?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`rhc deploy`](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/deployments.html#using-the-deploy-command)

```
rhc deploy master -a <app name>
```